# Bitcoin core - How to get transaction size before send BTC to an address

Tags: transactions, size, bitcoin, fee

How can I get transaction size before sending BTC to an external address?

I am using Bitcoin core to make the transactions, and I was trying to calculate transaction size.
So that I can use it to estimate transaction fee.
But couldn't find a way

Could you tell me its logic and method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign the transaction locally in your code, instead of using `bitcoind`. Then you simply measure the size of the transaction serialised as a byte stream.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. 
Could you explain about it more in detail?

Comment: I Googled a random article for you: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/03/create-sign-bitcoin-transactions-golang/ - You do not mention anything about the problem you are solving, so I cannot give you details, as you are not giving me details.

Answer (score 0):

After signing the transaction with either

- `signrawtransactionwithwallet`
- `signrawtransactionwithkey`
- `signrawtransaction` , this is deprecated and fully removed from bitcoind 0.18.0 and above.

It will return hex value in the result. Use `decoderawtransaction` to view your transaction before sending. In the result it has 'size' attribute showing the size of your transaction. Below is a snippet from bitcoind documentation.

```
...
  "txid" : "hex",           (string) The transaction id
  "hash" : "hex",           (string) The transaction hash (differs from txid for witness transactions)
  "size" : n,               (numeric) The transaction size
  "vsize" : n,              (numeric) The virtual transaction size (differs from size for witness transactions)
  "weight" : n,             (numeric) The transaction's weight (between vsize*4 - 3 and vsize*4)
 ...
```

However, if you are planning to broadcast a transaction with a known fee rate in mind, you should use `fundrawtransaction` to specify your transaction's fee rate etc.